# Error Caught in Page_Error event with no error message

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, asp-classic

I'm getting hundreds of these error emails on my site a day (I get emailed if there's a 500 server error).  The problem is the message isn't particularly useful, I can't seem to reproduce it or see what effect it is having on the visitors getting the errors.

One example of the full error message is:

> Error Message: Error Caught in Page_Error event
>
> Error in: http://www.scirra.com/forum/ Error Message: Stack Trace: at
>   System.Web.CachedPathData.ValidatePath(String physicalPath) at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.PipelineStepManager.ValidateHelper(HttpContext
>   context)
>
> Server Variables ALL_HTTP = HTTP_CONNECTION:keep-alive
>   HTTP_ACCEPT:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
>   HTTP_ACCEPT_CHARSET:windows-1251,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
>   HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING:gzip, deflate
>   HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE:ru-ru,ru;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
>   HTTP_COOKIE:scirralVisit=LV=***REMOVED***;
>   __utma=***REMOVED***; __utmz=***REMOVED***.utmcsr=scirraconstruct.ru|utmccn=(referral)|utmcmd=referral|utmcct=/community/blog/addons/281.html;
>   ASPSESSIONIDACTAQRCS=***REMOVED***;
>   scirrasID=SID=***REMOVED***;
>   __utmc=***REMOVED***; __utmb=***REMOVED*** HTTP_HOST:www.scirra.com HTTP_IF_NONE_MATCH:""
>   HTTP_REFERER:http://www.scirra.com/forum/plugin-network-v03a-update_topic43662_page3.html
>   HTTP_USER_AGENT:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:5.0) Gecko/20100101
>   Firefox/5.0
>
> ALL_RAW = Connection: keep-alive Accept:
>   text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
>   Accept-Charset: windows-1251,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7 Accept-Encoding:
>   gzip, deflate Accept-Language: ru-ru,ru;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
>   Cookie: scirralVisit=LV=***REMOVED***;
>   __utma=***REMOVED***; __utmz=***REMOVED***.utmcsr=scirraconstruct.ru|utmccn=(referral)|utmcmd=referral|utmcct=/community/blog/addons/281.html;
>   ASPSESSIONIDACTAQRCS=***REMOVED***;
>   scirrasID=SID=***REMOVED***;
>   __utmc=***REMOVED***; __utmb=***REMOVED*** Host: www.scirra.com If-None-Match: "" Referer:
>   http://www.scirra.com/forum/plugin-network-v03a-update_topic43662_page3.html
>   User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:5.0) Gecko/20100101
>   Firefox/5.0
>
> APPL_MD_PATH = /LM/W3SVC/1/ROOT APPL_PHYSICAL_PATH =
>   C:\Websites\Scirra\ AUTH_TYPE = AUTH_USER = AUTH_PASSWORD = LOGON_USER
>   = REMOTE_USER = CERT_COOKIE = CERT_FLAGS = CERT_ISSUER = CERT_KEYSIZE = CERT_SECRETKEYSIZE = CERT_SERIALNUMBER = CERT_SERVER_ISSUER = CERT_SERVER_SUBJECT = CERT_SUBJECT = CONTENT_LENGTH = 0 CONTENT_TYPE =
>   GATEWAY_INTERFACE = CGI/1.1 HTTPS = off HTTPS_KEYSIZE =
>   HTTPS_SECRETKEYSIZE = HTTPS_SERVER_ISSUER = HTTPS_SERVER_SUBJECT =
>   INSTANCE_ID = 1 INSTANCE_META_PATH = /LM/W3SVC/1 LOCAL_ADDR =
>   84.45.57.143 PATH_INFO = /forum/ PATH_TRANSLATED = C:\Websites\Scirra\forum\ QUERY_STRING = REMOTE_ADDR = ***REMOVED***
>   REMOTE_HOST = ***REMOVED*** REMOTE_PORT = 3939 REQUEST_METHOD = GET
>   SCRIPT_NAME = /forum/ SERVER_NAME = www.scirra.com SERVER_PORT = 80
>   SERVER_PORT_SECURE = 0 SERVER_PROTOCOL = HTTP/1.1 SERVER_SOFTWARE =
>   Microsoft-IIS/7.5 URL = /forum/ HTTP_CONNECTION = keep-alive
>   HTTP_ACCEPT =
>   text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
>   HTTP_ACCEPT_CHARSET = windows-1251,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
>   HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING = gzip, deflate HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE =
>   ru-ru,ru;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3 HTTP_COOKIE =
>   scirralVisit=LV=***REMOVED***;
>   __utma=***REMOVED***; __utmz=***REMOVED***.utmcsr=scirraconstruct.ru|utmccn=(referral)|utmcmd=referral|utmcct=/community/blog/addons/281.html;
>   ASPSESSIONIDACTAQRCS=***REMOVED***;
>   scirrasID=SID=***REMOVED***;
>   __utmc=***REMOVED***; __utmb=***REMOVED*** HTTP_HOST = www.scirra.com HTTP_IF_NONE_MATCH = "" HTTP_REFERER =
>   http://www.scirra.com/forum/plugin-network-v03a-update_topic43662_page3.html
>   HTTP_USER_AGENT = Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:5.0) Gecko/20100101
>   Firefox/5.0
>
> No virus found in this message. Checked by AVG - www.avg.com Version:
>   2012.0.1869 / Virus Database: 2092/4602 - Release Date: 11/07/11

The thing to note is:

- scirra.com/forum/ is a classic ASP application
- The rest of the site is ASP.net

Can anyone help me work out more about what this message means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just the other day was fighting with a similar problem, and the culprit was a malformed url generated by the user.

[image]

Comment: Awesome thanks!  It's the forum software, we turned RTE off because we don't like it and the non RTE editor really isn't very good at all and does things like this!